# Multitouch between different views on diffrent apps on android, ACTION_POINTER_DOWN not trigger

Tags: android, android-studio, ontouchlistener, multi-touch

ACTION_POINTER_DOWN works fine when I multitouch on the same view.

But when I multitouch on diffent apps, ACTION_POINTER_DOWN do not trigger.

one app is developed by myself, and the other is not.

So i can't add setOnTouchListener on all view.

The question is:

1. Why ACTION_POINTER_DOWN not working on touch different views?
2. How can i implement multitouch on diffent apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android seems not support multitouch views across apps. So you can't touch two app on the same time. But multi-window mode supports, i dont't know how this work, if somebody know, please comment.